# Como hacer la comprobacion de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, array

En este código, el arreglo password recibe de manera aleatoria 16 caracteres del arreglo container.

Lo que yo quiero es que una vez que los tenga hacer la comprobación de que al menos exista uno de cada tipo de carácter(mayúsculas, minúsculas, números y símbolos).

Tengo dos consultas. Primero que array method puedo usar y como para no hacer lo que hice ahí y segundo porque no esta funcionando de manera correcta el if de la function comprobación? si muchas veces tiene al menos un caracter de cada tipo y entra en else.

```
const container = [ mayusculas = ["Q", "W", "E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"],minusculas = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"],numeros = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,],simbolos =  ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "/", "(",")", "=", "?", "¿", "¡", ",", ".", "-", "_"]];
let password = [];
//let cantidad = prompt('Indique cuantos caracteres debe tener la clave');
generarPassword();
comprobacion();

function generarPassword(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 16/*cantidad*/; i ++){
        let caracter = container [Math.floor(Math.random()* container.length)] [Math.floor(Math.random()* container.length)];
        password.push(caracter);
    }
}

function comprobacion(){
    if(password.includes("Q"|| "W"|| "E"||"R"||"T"||"Y"||"U"||"I"||"O"||"P"||"A"||"S"||"D"||"F"||"G"||"H"||"J"||"K"||"L"||"Z"||"X"||"C"||"V"||"B"||"N"||"M") && password.includes("q"||"w"||"e"||"r"||"t"||"y"||"u"||"i"||"o"||"p"||"a"||"s"||"d"||"f"||"g"||"h"||"j"||"k"||"l"||"z"||"x"||"c"||"v"||"b"||"n"||"m") && password.includes(0|| 1|| 2|| 3|| 4|| 5|| 6|| 7|| 8|| 9) && password.includes("!"|| "@"|| "#"|| "$"|| "%"|| "&"|| "/"|| "("||")"|| "="|| "?"|| "¿"|| "¡"|| ","|| "."|| "-"|| "_")){
        console.log('hay mayusculas, minusculas,numeros y caracteres especiales');
    }else{ console.log('no hay mayusculas, minusculas, numeros o caracteres espesciales');}
};

console.table(password);
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = password.join('');
```

Comment: Para "comprobacion" podrías haber utilizado mejor expresiones regulares. Échale un vistazo a esto: [Expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Son un fastidio, pero luego son muy útiles y aprovechables, además de que, por ejemplo, en tu código, te ahorran trabajo.

Comment: Deberías indentar correctamente el código, si eres vago hay herramientas online, buscando "js beaty", por ejemplo: https://beautifier.io/

Answer (score 0):

A tu primera pregunta, ***la forma habitual de verificar la presencia o no de determinados caracteres es un string o un array es usando expresiones regulares***.
Para validar una contraseña tienes por ejemplo:

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z]\w{10,32}$/;
// mayúsculas, minúsculas y longitud de entre 10 y 32 caracteres.
```

o esta otra, de [está página](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/use-regex-to-test-password-strength-in-javascript/), más completa que incluye números y usa serie de caracteres especiales:

```
var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");
```

*En la [página de origen](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/use-regex-to-test-password-strength-in-javascript/) explica cada grupo de la expresión.*

Veras que ambas expresiones regulares tienen una sintaxis diferente, esto siempre es un problema sino sabes mucho de *regex*, para usarlas:

```
const boolResult = (password.match(regex));
```

o

```
const boolResult = (strongRegex.test(password));
```

respectivamente.

Y en un ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        const CHAR_GROUPS = [
            ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'S'],
            ['q', 'w', 'e', 's'],
            [0, 1, 2, 3],
            ['!', '@', '#', '!'],
        ];

        //let cantidad = prompt('Indique cuantos caracteres debe tener la clave');
        const strPassword = randomStr();
        if (checkPwStrong(strPassword)) {
            console.log('weak OK');
        } else {
            console.log('strong ERR');
        }

        if (checkPwStrong(strPassword)) {
            console.log('strong OK');
        } else {
            console.log('strong ERR');
        }

        function randomNumber(min, max) // int
        {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        }

        function randomStr(longitud = 16) // string
        {
            const password = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
                const randomGroup = CHAR_GROUPS[randomNumber(0, CHAR_GROUPS.length)];
                // console.log(randomGroup); // HACK: show the used char group

                const randomChar = randomGroup[randomNumber(0, randomGroup.length)];
                password.push(randomChar);
            }

            return password.join('');
        }

        function checkPwStrong(password, useStrong = true) // bool
        {
            const weakRegex = /^[A-Za-z]\w{10,32}$/;
            const strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");

            return (useStrong)
                ? (strongRegex.test(password))
                : (password.match(weakRegex));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, a primera vista no se ve el problema, el código es confuso de interpretar y algo esta mal en tu función generadora, usas el número de grupos de caracteres que usas como parámetro para generar los caracteres, que creo que es incorrecto, lo ves si reduces los caracteres de algun grupo por debajo de ese número, ya que generas algunos *undefined*. He modificado y reducido los grupos para poder ver mejor que esta ocurriendo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        const CHAR_GROUPS = [
            ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'S'],
            ['q', 'w', 'e', 's'],
            [0, 1, 2, 3],
            ['!', '@', '#', '!'],
        ];

        //let cantidad = prompt('Indique cuantos caracteres debe tener la clave');
        const strPassword = randomStr();
        if (checkPwStrong(strPassword)) {
            console.log('OK');
        } else {
            console.log('ERR');
        }

        function randomNumber(min, max) // int
        {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        }

        function randomStr(longitud = 16) // string
        {
            const password = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
                const randomGroup = CHAR_GROUPS[randomNumber(0, CHAR_GROUPS.length)];
                console.log(randomGroup); // HACK: show the used char group

                const randomChar = randomGroup[randomNumber(0, randomGroup.length)];
                password.push(randomChar);
            }

            return password.join('');
        }

        function checkPwStrong(password) // bool
        {
            console.log(password);

            if (password.includes('Q' || 'W' || 'E' || 'S')
                && password.includes('q' || 'w' || 'e' || 's')
                && password.includes(0 || 1 || 2 || 3)
                && password.includes('!' || '@' || '#' || '!')) {

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Al trazar el grupo que se usa al obtener cada caracter se ve mejor que se estan obteniendo caracteres de cada uno de los grupos, si bien esto podría no ocurrir si se reduce la longitud de la contraseña.
El problema debe estar en la función de comprobación. Para acotarlo comprobar que pasa para cada grupo de caracteres, separando los condicionales:

```
if (password.includes('Q' || 'W' || 'E' || 'S')) {
    console.log(1);
    if (password.includes('q' || 'w' || 'e' || 's')) {
        console.log(2);
        if (password.includes(0 || 1 || 2 || 3)) {
            console.log(3);
            if (password.includes('!' || '@' || '#' || '!')) {
                console.log(4);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si se ejecuta el script varias veces, se ve que va fallando en uno u otro de los diferentes grupos, algunas veces pasa todos, pero raramente y creo que los positivos se reducen si aumentas el número de caracteres sobre los que validar dentro de [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) *aclarar que esta función se usa tanto para validar un string como un array en JS*. Creo que el problema puede ser su uso, al usar como parámetro algo como: 'Q' || 'W' || 'E' || 'S'.
Nunca lo había hecho ni visto, ¿cómo funciona? ¿coje el primer caracter? ¿el último? ¿al azar? ¿prueba uno a uno que sería el caso en el que funcionaría?

Replantearía la función de validación, p.e.:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        const CHAR_GROUPS = [
            ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'S'],
            ['q', 'w', 'e', 's'],
            [0, 1, 2, 3],
            ['!', '@', '#', '!'],
        ];

        //let cantidad = prompt('Indique cuantos caracteres debe tener la clave');
        const strPassword = randomStr();
        if (checkPwStrong(strPassword)) {
            console.log('OK');
        } else {
            console.log('ERR');
        }

        function randomNumber(min, max) // int
        {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        }

        function randomStr(longitud = 16) // string
        {
            const password = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
                const randomGroup = CHAR_GROUPS[randomNumber(0, CHAR_GROUPS.length)];
                // console.log(randomGroup); // HACK: show the used char group

                const randomChar = randomGroup[randomNumber(0, randomGroup.length)];
                password.push(randomChar);
            }

            return password.join('');
        }

        function checkPwStrong(password) // bool
        {
            console.log(password);

            for (let i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
                let char = password[i];
                if (char == parseInt(char)) {
                    char = parseInt(char);
                }

                if (!checkIsCharIsOnSomeGroup(char, CHAR_GROUPS)) {
                    console.log('FALLA: ' + char)
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;


            function checkIsCharIsOnSomeGroup(char, charGroups) // bool
            {
                for (let j = 0; j < charGroups.length; j++) {
                    const arrChars = charGroups[j];

                    if (arrChars.includes(char)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

En la función de validación tuve que añadir, código extra:

```
let char = password[i];
if (char == parseInt(char)) {
    char = parseInt(char);
}
```

ya que al obtener el carácter de una cadena y no saber si es un número `includes` siempre daría `false`, ya que se compara un string con una serie de enteros:

```
[0,1,2,3].includes('1'); // false
```

Y por esto se usan regex...